# How can I install Boost 1.50 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: installation, application-development, c++, boost

The libboost-dev package in the repos is an older one and I would like to use the newest release. I'm OK with installing from source, but am a little confused by the instructions on the site. It instructs to run

```
./b2 install --prefix=PREFIX
```

> where PREFIX is a directory where you want Boost.Build to be installed.

What should PREFIX be set to so that the libraries and headers are available for the compilers to find without specifying custom paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gcc  --print-search-dirs
```

with this command you get informations about where gcc looks for libs and headers, probably the best place where you can install your custom library is

```
/usr/lib
```

but the problem is always the same, if you will install the same package from a repository in a next future you will probably experience some problem.

If i was in you, i will install each one of my custom library into a custom directory and instruct gcc with a specific directory named at compile time.

Comment: FWIW the correct PREFIX is /usr, since Boost will copy files to PREFIX/lib and PREFIX/include (I don't why they can't state this simply, I would have known the path just from that).